# invoke method problem with form object in c#

Tags: c#, forms, object, invoke

I am developing a chat application with C# and we are using System.Timer.Timer for frequently getting data for the new request and zone request.

It is running fine but whenever we create a new instance a cross threaded operation exception occurs.

This is my code:

```
frmchat f = new frmchat();
MethodInvoker method = new MethodInvoker(delegate()
{
    f.Name = "xyz";f.Show();
});
if (f.InvokeRequired)
{
    f.Invoke(method);
}
else
{
    method();
}
```

This will create a number of chat forms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are creating that form at the elapsed event handler of that timer then use `this.Invoke` instead, like:

```
this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() =>
{
    frmchat f = new frmchat();
    f.Name = "xyz";
    f.Show();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing your problem is new forms can only be created on the UI thread. Try to use a [Windows.Forms.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx) if possible. This will reinvoke the event on the correct thread automagicly for you.

Comment: yes if i use window.forms.timer the runnig fine but my ui is not responding when code between timer is running.thats why i use this please do something.

Comment: Using Control.Invoke() is not going to fix that.  The invoke target won't run for the same reason that the timer's Tick event won't run.  Fix the real problem, whatever it is.

Comment: if u have any idea to open form on timerelapse event then please give me.one any way.

Comment: I recommend creating a very small project where you only create the new forms and let that form be an empty form. If you can get that to work you will learn from that example and can perhaps easier see what goes wrong in your real project?

Comment: not anyting wrong in the real project only this timer wise having a problem,if i use system.windoe.form.timer instead of system.timers.timer  then this all running fine.if any help it will appreciated.